# (Colab) created env for python 3.6 but scipy for 3.7 is installed

Tags: python, scipy, conda, google-colaboratory, torch

On CoLab I created new env with python 3.6

```
!add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
!apt-get update
!apt-get install python3.6
!apt-get install python3.6-dev

!wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python3.6 get-pip.py

import sys

sys.path[2] = '/usr/lib/python36.zip'
sys.path[3] = '/usr/lib/python3.6'
sys.path[4] = '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload'
sys.path[5] = '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages'
sys.path[7] ='/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/extensions'
```

which returns

```
['',
 '/content',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/root/.ipython']
```

so I deleted python 3.7 packages

```
sys.path.remove(r"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages")
sys.path.remove(r"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions")
```

Then I installed

```
!pip install scipy
!pip install torch==1.3.0 torchvision==0.4.1
```

There are two problems to it:

1. scipy is installed to python 3.7 directory

```
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from scipy) (1.19.5)
```

It returns error:

```
cannot import name 'imread' from 'scipy.misc' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/misc/__init__.py)
```

2. running a python file returns No module named 'torch' error

```
!python3.6 caption.py --img='/content/Image_Captioning/1584945532990.jpg' --model='/content/Image_Captioning/BEST_checkpoint_coco_5_cap_per_img_5_min_word_freq.pth.tar' --word_map='/content/Image_Captioning/WORDMAP_coco_5_cap_per_img_5_min_word_freq.json' --beam_size=5
```

Does anyone have solutions to these problems?
Thank you for your time

Comment: Try forcing the correct python executable by running `!python3.6 -m pip install scipy` instead of `!pip install scipy`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

running the code `!python3.6 -m pip install scipy` locally solved the problem. Credits to Adid's comment.